# How can i send edittext value to multiple uid in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

After successfully collecting uid from firebase realtime database  and store the value in arraylist, I need to send the edit text value to multiple uid in firebase database, how can I do this any idea.iam new to Androidstudio..

Comment: You should also post your code so it becomes easier to understand your problem

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and show us what exactly you want to achieve. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.